# Meta refresh tag not redirecting with noscript tags

Tags: javascript, php, html, meta-tags, noscript

I have a `<noscript>` tag with a meta refresh in it, but when I turn off the browsers javascript, it doesn’t redirect. Here is my code:

```
<noscript>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://mysite.tld/javascript-disabled.html" />
</noscript>
```

here is my code after the meta tag, and before it:

```
 <html>
 <head>
<noscript>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://mysite.tld/javascript-disabled.html" />
</noscript>
</html>
</head>
```

This is in a `PHP` file so I do have php script as follows, if that is interfering:

```
<?php
 echo "window.alert('test')";
?>
```

I cant use php header to redirect, like I know is possible, because headers are already called in `header.php`

I also tried:

```
<?php
 echo "<noscript>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://mysite.tld/javascript-disabled.html" />
</noscript>";
?>
```

But that causes a php error output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error cause by the quote. Try change it to:

```
<?php
 echo "<noscript>
<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=http://mysite.tld/javascript-disabled.html' />
</noscript>";
?>
```

But i'm dought if this will work.

A diffrent approach will be to create a non-javascript page and use javascript to redirect. Something like:

```
window.location.assign("jsenable.html")
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. I will try and let you know .

Answer (score -1):

The error with the html line is that you have the <\head> closing tag after the <\html> closing tag. It should be the other way.

Comment: While that is *an* error, it is not responsible for the problem the question is asking about. The real problem was identified by the accepted answer four years ago.